# Relationship between two operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplacian

> We consider the following to operators acting over regular functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
>   $$\Delta u(\overline{x})=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2_1}(\overline{x})+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2_2}(\overline{x}); \qquad \overline{x}=(x_1,x_2),$$
>   $$Lu(\overline{x})=\lim_{r\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\int_{|\overline{y}|<r}(u(\overline{x}+\overline{y})-u(\overline{x}))d\overline{y}\right); \qquad r=0,$$
>   Is there any relationship between the operators $\Delta$ and $L$? In affirmative case, is this relationship restrited to the two dimensional case?

I've studied a course of harmonic functions and partial differential equations, but I found this exercise and I have no idea how to begin to solve it. I will appreciate any help or hint because I'm completely lost.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function look at the mean value property.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're saying. Should I look ay anything special?

Comment: I said where to look, there is a section with the mean value property. Is that not similar to what you wrote?

Comment: Ir doesn't seem to me

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Your operator $L$ is zero on continuous $u$, right?